# Keep form centred but unchanging

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to keep a form centred in the screen however when I add extra text such as an error message the whole input box shifts to centre the error text as well.
I only want the form text box's centred and everything after just added on to the right.

Sample code:

```
<div style="width:60%; text-align: center; background-color: #70b08e; margin: 0 auto;">
        <span class="error">*Required feild</span>
        <br><br>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <label for="name">User name:</label><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" maxlength=255>
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        <label for="email">E-Mail:</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" maxlength=255>
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>  value="male">Male
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </form>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Move this out of the parent div :  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span> and style it as text-align center

Comment: So you're saying to put that inside an adjacent div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is how you want it.

```css
.input-grp {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.error {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:60%; text-align: center; background-color: #70b08e; margin: 0 auto;">
  <span class="global-error">*Required feild</span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <form method="post">
    <div class="input-grp">
      <label for="name">User name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="" maxlength=255>
      <span class="error">error message</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="input-grp">
      <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="" maxlength=255>
      <span class="error">email error</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="input-grp">

      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password">
      <span class="error">pass error</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="input-grp">
      <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
      <span class="error"></span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that's perfect thank you very much. So 'position: absolute' means that it won't affect anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Change `text-align: center;` by `text-align: right;` here :

```
<div style="width:60%; text-align: right; background-color: #70b08e; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Also this :

```
<div class="error" style="text-align: center;">*Required feild</div>
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8axxk71w/)

Comment: This doesn't help as i still want the form centred. Thanks anyway

Comment: If you cut out all the <?php?> inside the <span> and replace it with text the form becomes off centre. That's the main problem

Comment: This is what it currently looks like however i want the form text boxes to stay centred with the errors right next to them. https://jsfiddle.net/8axxk71w/3/

Comment: The boxes become off centre when the error message become long.